# How to integrate Langchain's Human Tool into Streamlit

Tags: python, streamlit, langchain

I'm using Langchain's Human Tool as part of my application. However, I am having difficulty integrating it into streamlit.

I'm mainly trying to change the `input_func` argument in the function:

```
Human_Tool =load_tools(["human"], lm=llm, input_func=get_input)
```

I've tried many different approaches but have not had success yet.

Here are some of the things I've tried:

```
   import streamlit as st

    def get_input() -> str:
        st.write("Insert your text below.")
        
        # Updated this line to include a label and hide it using label_visibility
        user_input = st.text_area(label="Your Text", value="", height=100, key=None, help=None, on_change=None, args=None, kwargs=None, label_visibility="hidden")
        
        submit_button = st.button("Submit")

        if submit_button:
            return user_input.strip()  # This will return the text entered by the user
        
        if not submit_button:
            with st.empty():
                for remaining in range(3600, 0, -1):
                    st.write(f"You have {remaining//60} minutes and {remaining%60} seconds to enter the text.")
                    time.sleep(1)
                    st.empty()

        return ""  # Returning empty if no input after an hour or not submitted
```

The code above opens a streamlit box that and accepts the user's input but it does not pass the users input to the agent.

```
import streamlit as st
import uuid

def get_input() -> str:
    unique_key = str(uuid.uuid4())  

    user_input = st.text_area(
        "Insert your text below:",
        key=f"uniqueTextAreaKey_{unique_key}",
        value="",
        height=200,
    )

    if st.button("Submit", key=f"uniqueButtonKey_{unique_key}"):
        if user_input:  # check if user input is not empty
            st.session_state['user_input'] = user_input
            st.session_state['submitted'] = True

            st.success("Input submitted successfully!")
            return user_input.strip()

    elif 'submitted' in st.session_state and st.session_state['submitted']:
        st.success("Input already submitted.")
        return st.session_state['user_input'].strip()

    else:
        st.warning("Please enter text and press submit.")

    return ""
```

This code also opens up a streamlit text box but gets stuck in an infinite loop.

**I want to ask what might be a `get_input` function for langchains' Human Tool that integrates successfully with streamlit.**